# adding a search Path in SWI prolog

Tags: prolog

In many Prolog systems it is easy to add a new search path for consulting file.
In Yap for example, the predicate I know it is add_to_path(NewPath).
Is there a way to do the same in SWI Prolog ?. My question is specifically about adding one path to the already existing paths, I am aware of the file_search_path/2 predicate for declaring directories, and the cd/1 predicate for changing the current directory, but I would like to know if there is an alternative method, like the one I found in Yap.

thanks in advance !

Comment: @David: The question is not specific to SWI.

Comment: The title is not relevant: The question itself is not specific to SWI.

Comment: Well, the tags are ORed, so...

Comment: @DavidTonhofer: It's ok to let SWI be mentioned in the question, after all, it **might** be of relevance. But once you look at the answers, you clearly see that it is not relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several mechanisms to this. The first one I met was in [C-Prolog](http://www.cs.duke.edu/csl/docs/cprolog.html), which indeed used clauses for `library_directory/1`. The current SWI-Prolog mechanism is derived from Quintus and also used in SICStus. It generalises from the `library_directory/1` approach
be treating expressions of the form `<alias>(Path)` as a search over the path-alias `<alias>`.

Paths for an alias are defined using the predicate [file_search_path/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=file_search_path/2).  Now, `library` is just an alias.  Normally, libraries are added using a clause `file_search_path(library, Dir)`.

This mechanism has proven to be pretty flexible.  Of course, it would be nice if Prolog systems get more compatible here.  I think todays YAP also supports the `file_search_path` system. (2016 Edit: It does indeed, see [YAP Prolog User's Manual: Changing the Compiler’s Behavior](http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~vsc/Yap/documentation.html#Setting-the-Compiler))

Comment: And here is how to add your path: `assertz(file_search_path(mine,'/home/quux')).` Then list everything using `findall(sol(X,Y),file_search_path(X,Y),Bag).`

Answer (score 6):

In your `.plrc`/`.yaprc`/`.sicstusrc`/`.swiplrc`:

```
 :- multifile(library_directory/1).
 library_directory('/home/ulrich/lftp/Prolog-inedit').
```

Comment: Hi!,I tried with some variations of this answer but I did not manage to add my path in the search path. First I tried typing exactly what you wrote (changing the path of course), then I tried replacing the second line by: :- asserta(library_directory('myLongPath'))., and finally I tried replacing the first line with :- multifile(library_directory('myLongPath'))., but nothing seemed to work. What I am trying to do is being able to consult any file F located in 'myLongPath', only with its name (e.g., [F]) and even if I am not in the same directory where the file is. Thanks for any clarification!

Comment: After more experiments I discovered that after using library_directory/1, I am supposed to import modules in that location as [library(ModuleName)]. Then apparently in SWI it is not possible to configure a global path from which files could be imported just with [ModuleName] (but please someone tell me if I am wrong! it is a bit strange I can do it easily in YAP or XSB but not in SWI). It is not that I mind to write library(...), but I think this could be a problem from a portability point of view, since as far as I know other prologs (e.g., XSB) do not allow to write file paths in that way.

Comment: this answer helps me very much!

Comment: From [library_directory/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=library_directory/1): " Deprecated. New code should use file_search_path/2."

Comment: @DavidTonhofer: SICStus supports both and there is no sign of deprecation. And in SWI, there are currently only [two places](http://www.swi-prolog.org/show-tag?tag=deprecated) that are tagged deprecated. Not sure were you get this from.

Comment: @false Just follow the link to the SWI doc as given. It's right there in the text as quoted. I also added the "deprecated" tag now.